# TextMate: How do I move my cursor out of the quotations without using the arrow keys?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

I was programming in PHP and typing `mysql_connect`, and by default the single-quotation is automatically closed, so I would have something like this `mysql_connect('localhost[cursor is here]')`. I still need to type my username and password, it just seems really out of the way to press the right arrow key to escape the single-quotations for writing the other arguments (username/password). Is there a hot key similar to `ctrl+enter` that can help move my cursor out of the quotations but not to the next line?

Comment: I don't use TextMate myself, but most editors I've seen let you type the character corresponding to the auto-closed part to skip over it. What happens if you press `'`?

Comment: That definitely works, but I'm trying to see if there are more ways.

Answer (score 1):

I often use Cmd-Right Arrow to move the the end of the line. I also make heavy use of Opt-Right Arrow and Opt-Left Arrow to move words at a time instead of characters.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was to record my own macro; it moves the caret to the right, inserts a comma and then a space. I've mapped the macro to *command* and *<* (shift and comma). Activating the macro on your code results in:

```
mysql_connect('localhost', [cursor is here])
```